# Bash: readline+vim jumps into cmd mode in forward-history-search and upon pressing Delete

Tags: bash, readline

I am using the vim mode in my bash (i.e. I setup readline to use vim mode through `~/.inputrc`).

If I do a `history-search-backward` and then  `history-search-forward` in insert mode with some characters already typed, the bash jumps to command mode when the forward-search arrives at the end.

For example, this happens when I:

- Type `echo "foo"`
- Type `e`
- Press Up Arrow (prompt shows `echo "foo"` in insert mode)
- Press Down Arrow (prompt shows `echo "foo"` in command mode)

It does not happen if I omit the step where I type `e`.

Furthermore, bash also jumps to command mode whenever I press the `Delete` key, plus it toggles capitalization.

For example, this happens when I:

- Type `echi`
- Move left
- Press `Delete` (prompt shows `ecHi` in command mode)

This happens independent of moving left, only the letter that is toggled changes.

(The first phenomenon occurs exactly the same way in `ipython`, which also uses `readline`. The second phenomenon is a bit diferent in `ipython`: Pressing delete in command mode does what it's supposed to do, pressing delete in insert mode also does what it's supposed to do, unless I am at the end of the line, in which case it also jumps back to command mode, but does not toggle capitalization.)

**EDIT** To fix the problem with the `Delete` key, put `"\e[3~": delete-char` in your '~/.inputrc`

I am using the following `.inputrc`:

```
  1 set editing-mode vi
  2 set keymap vi-command
  3 "\e[A":history-search-backward
  4 "\e[B":history-search-forward
  5 "\e[C":forward-char
  6 "\e[D":backward-char
  7 ##
  8 "j":history-search-forward
  9 "k":history-search-backward
 10 set keymap vi-insert
 11 "\e[A":history-search-backward
 12 "\e[B":history-search-forward
 13 "\e[C":forward-char
 14 "\e[D":backward-char
 15 ##
 16 set show-mode-in-prompt on
 17 ##
 18 set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[2 q\2\1\e[1;31m\2(cmd)\1\e[0m\2"
 19 set vi-ins-mode-string "\1\e[5 q\2(ins)"
 20 ##
 21 set keymap vi-insert
 22 RETURN "\e\n"
 23 set keymap vi-command
 24 v: ""
```

and the following `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
set shellslash
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
set ff=unix
nmap <CR> o<Esc>
set number
set showcmd
```

Comment: Use `cat` or Ctrl-V to see what the keys are actually sending - maybe there's an extra escape in there somewhere?

Comment: @muru `Delete` is sending `^[[3~`

Comment: I don't really understand what this means, but I do know that tilde toggles case in vim. So you seem to be up to something

Comment: So you need to bing `\e[3~` in readline to the delete function, whatever it maybe called. I'm removing the vim tag, since the **vi** mode in readline is not actually using vi or Vim, but is a partial re-implementation of some functionality present in vi.

Comment: @muru `"\e[3~": delete-char` Thanks a lot. That solves one problem. Any idea about the other?